# How to automatically start a second skype entity at Windows start

Tags: windows-vista, skype

I learned from the Skype forum that it is possible to run several Skype instances at a time by running them with different system users (need to be Administrators and have password).

How would I go about starting up my second skype instance with another user automatically at startup? Is there a way to write a batch for such a task?

Comment: Edited my post ... skype launcher has a auto logon feature for multiple accounts have added a link which explains it all.. this should take care of the whole problem so no need to write a batch script at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Skype Launcher](http://download.cnet.com/SkypeLauncher/3000-2349_4-10844575.html) allows you to open and sign into multiple instances / user accounts of skype. With this program you don't have to hassle yourself with user permissions.
Hope this helps

### **Auto-Login feature:**

If you want to use the Autologin feature, simple start the SkypeLauncher_config.exe and add your Skype accounts. When you now start the SkypeLauncher.exe it will login all saved accounts. To return to "old" behavior, simple delete all saved accounts with the SkypeLauncher_config.exe.
The credentials are stored AES encrypted in the registry.

You *must* disable the "Sign me in when skype start" feature in Skype!

More info [here](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=88055)

Comment: thanks for pointing me to skype launcher, it's exactly what I need and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this automatically with a batch. The only tool you'd have at your disposal there would be [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) which always prompts for the password, you can't supply it via the command line. Arguably a security feature.

What you could do is to set up a Scheduled Task that runs on log-on and starts Skype as a different user. Scheduled Tasks use cached credentials, that's why you get asked for them when you set it up. This might work, though I'm not entirely sure whether the user running the program and the user having to log on can be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can start as many instances as you want, here is an example for two, just create a batch file :

```
@ECHO OFF
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary /username:yourusername /password:yourpassword
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 > nul
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary /username:yourusername2 /password:yourpassword2
```

- Edit your username and password.
- save under `.bat`
- Add to your startup folder.

Note : You might need to change program url as your system.

Comment: What are those `ping` commands doing there?

Comment: this is a brilliant solution. not sure why it's not upvoted :). worked perfectly fine for me. 

@anyone-interested - the pings are to introduce a delay between the skype starts. i changed it to 

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul (1 second sleep) for the first one and 2 seconds thereafter.

Comment: Skype is now forcing new accounts to be made with a Microsoft account. This script launches the program, but fails to login to Microsoft. It fills the username but not the password. Any ideas?